# Can't set DateTime field to a default value through XML in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I need to set a DateTime field to a default value of one year from the current date. I've used the following XML syntax:

```
<Default>=DATE(YEAR(Today)+1,MONTH(Today),DAY(Today))</Default>
```

It's not working and bombs the list containing this field. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [DefaultFormula](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms455738.aspx) instead.

[Deploying column level validations in a feature](http://www.3guysonsharepoint.com/?p=364) gives an example using the same formula in a `DefaultFormula` element instead of `Default`.

Comment: Thank you so very much. It worked like a charm. Basically, the final thing markup was the following:                                       <DefaultFormula>=DATE(YEAR(Today)+1,MONTH(Today),DAY(Today))</DefaultFormula>                                                                                                                        Would you also be so kind as to try to answer another question that I've posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343574/how-can-i-set-a-user-field-to-a-default-value-of-a-user-currently-logged-in-thro? Again, I really appreciate it.